# How to create drag and drop widgets for DotNetNuke?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dotnetnuke

I wanted to recreate this widget drag and drop effect in DotNetNuke: http://templatebuilder.sitefinity.com

I am not sure where to start but I think this would be incredibly useful in other CMS's. Anyone know how to make this generic enough to use in other CMS's?

Comment: What does this have to do with Orchard?

Comment: If generic enough, I would love to see this in Orchard too. Moreso since the interface is so confusing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of DotNetNuke 6.0, this is something that could be accomplished with a bit of [widget building](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Widget.aspx).  This is because [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) is included by default in the core.  So, the drag and drop capabilities are offered to anyone with the skill set to take advantage of them.  As far as how you begin to build the widgets to get this done, follow the link above.  It will show you resources that can help you begin to build widgets.

I for one would love to see this capability in the core of DotNetNuke myself.  I happen to know of some custom DotNetNuke control panels out there that do this very thing, but they have been built specifically for private company use only.